# How do I replace the similar looking values in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-analysis

I am new to Pandas. I have the following data types in my dataset. (The dataset is Indian Startup Funding downloaded from Kaggle.)

```
Date                datetime64[ns]
StartupName                 object
IndustryVertical            object
CityLocation                object
InvestorsName               object
InvestmentType              object
AmountInUSD                 object
dtype: object

data['AmountInUSD'].groupby(data['CityLocation']).describe()
```

I did the above operation and found that many cities are similar for example,

```
Bangalore   
Bangalore / Palo Alto
Bangalore / SFO
Bangalore / San Mateo
Bangalore / USA
Bangalore/ Bangkok
```

I want to do following operation, but I do not know the code to this.

**In column CityLocation, find all cells which starts with 'Bang' and replace them all with 'Bangalore'. Help will be appreciated.**

I did this

```
data[data.CityLocation.str.startswith('Bang')]
```

and I do not know what to do after this.

Comment: please show what code you have written

Comment: data[data.CityLocation.str.startswith('Bang')]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pandas 0.23 has a nice way to handle text. See the docs [Working with Text Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html). You can use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to capture and replace text.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'CityLocation': ["Bangalore / Palo Alto", "Bangalore / SFO", "Other"]})

df['CityLocation'] = df['CityLocation'].str.replace("^Bang.*", "Bangalore")

print(df)
```

Will yield

```
  CityLocation
0    Bangalore
1    Bangalore
2        Other
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked. I will do the same with other cities in the data.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `loc` function to find the values in your column whose substring matches and replace with them with the value of your choosing.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'CityLocation': ['Bangalore', 'Dangerlore', 'Bangalore/USA'], 'Values': [1, 2, 3]})
print(df)
#     CityLocation  Values
# 0      Bangalore       1
# 1     Dangerlore       2
# 2  Bangalore/USA       3


df.loc[df.CityLocation.str.startswith('Bang'), 'CityLocation'] = 'Bangalore'
print(df)
#   CityLocation  Values
# 0    Bangalore       1
# 1   Dangerlore       2
# 2    Bangalore       3
```

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the answer :) , but it is the string itself that I want to change. I do not want to change the Values corresponding to Bangalore and Dangerlore.